# Upload php application to amazon?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a `.php` application that i would like to be able to run from any browser.
This application is sending push to mobile phone using `ssl` .

I have a website in amazon, and i have changed the `index.html` file to my file `index.php` ( did that in my website `bucket` ).

Now its not working, and i guess its because a .php application needs to use another service .

My question is what amazon service i have to use, to be able to upload and run my .php file as quickly as possible. (the file uses a certificate `.mem` file )

I could see you have a php sdk , and i can figure out if i need that . They have a lots of guides there .

Answer (score 0):

AWS S3 is for *static files* only. It will serve your php as if it's simply a file, it does not execute programs.

Your choices for PHP on AWS are to use [Elastic Beanstalk](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_PHP_eb.html) or to [configure your own EC2 instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-LAMP.html).

There are many nuances to this, especially the EC2 approach.